# How to fix eslint error - extraneous node/no-extraneous-require

Tags: node.js, eslint

How do I fix the complain when eslint is run on a node.js file that uses async library?

```
eslint output
<file name>
14:23  error  "async" is extraneous  node/no-extraneous-require
```

Comment: I do not like how the question was down voted. I upvoted again. Please keep in mind that some error message are some times difficult to understand for non english native speakers. In this case I expected that code will not run by default if required module was not defined in required dependencies. How ever the question pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exactly as error description says

If a require()'s target is extraneous (**it's not written in package.json**), the program works in local, but will not work after dependencies are re-installed. It will cause troubles to your team/contributors. This rule disallows require() of extraneous modules.

But if it's how you need to do it anyway the you can add an exception in your rules

```
"rules": {
  "node/no-extraneous-require": ["error", {
  "allowModules": ["yourModule"]
  }]
}
```